# Jenkins Ruby metrics plugin fail to copy .gitkeep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins

Jenkins Ruby metrics plugin cause error when copy .gitkeep file to log directory, because it fails to create log directory.

Error message is below.

```
Publishing rcov report...

ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.rubyMetrics.rcov.RcovPublisher aborted due to exception
Failed to copy /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/RailsApp/workspace/log/.gitkeep to /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/RailsApp/builds/2014-02-05_21-07-52/log/.gitkeep due to failed to create the parent directory for /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/RailsApp/builds/2014-02-05_21-07-52/log/.gitkeep
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Copy.doFileOperations(Copy.java:914)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Copy.execute(Copy.java:567)
    at hudson.Util.copyFile(Util.java:922)
    at hudson.FilePath$38$1.visit(FilePath.java:1937)
    at hudson.util.DirScanner.scanSingle(DirScanner.java:49)
    at hudson.util.DirScanner$Glob.scan(DirScanner.java:131)
    at hudson.FilePath$38.invoke(FilePath.java:1932)
    at hudson.FilePath$38.invoke(FilePath.java:1925)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:914)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:887)
    at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:1925)
    at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:1911)
    at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:1894)
    at hudson.plugins.rubyMetrics.Utils.moveReportsToBuildRootDir(Utils.java:28)
    at hudson.plugins.rubyMetrics.Utils.moveReportsToBuildRootDir(Utils.java:12)
    at hudson.plugins.rubyMetrics.HtmlPublisher.prepareMetricsReportBeforeParse(HtmlPublisher.java:30)
    at hudson.plugins.rubyMetrics.rcov.RcovPublisher.perform(RcovPublisher.java:50)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:784)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:756)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:705)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1695)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to create the parent directory for /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/RailsApp/builds/2014-02-05_21-07-52/log/.gitkeep
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ResourceUtils.copyResource(ResourceUtils.java:512)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:559)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Copy.doFileOperations(Copy.java:899)
    ... 25 more
```

Jenkins didn't create log 'directory' but log 'file'. Jenkins have permission to read/write of the directory of course. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess that the problem is log file which created by Jenkins.
Jenkins creates log file in build root directory and it prevents to create log directory since it has same name. Hmm... is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I spend a lot of time to fix this issue.

In fact, when you activate the [Ruby metrics plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ruby+Metrics+Plugin), you have to provide a directory. If you don't, the default folder is **log**, and it is the cause of your error.

So, go to your project configuration and in the **Publish Rcov Report** section, you just fill the directory.

Enjoy :)